# trim the output of the command using AWK

Tags: linux, awk

I have been working to setup my own DNS server using FreeBSD and I have done almost everything.
In order to write a custom script for logging and monitoring different domains in the zones, I am using `host -a -l mydomain.com` command, that displays all the sub domains in the give domain. I am writing the output of this command to a file using `> output`.
The problem is, the output has some other data as well which is of no interest for me.

The output of this command have following sections,

```
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6149
;; flags: qr aa ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 45, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;unix.                          IN      AXFR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
abc.unix
xyz.unix

Received 1108 bytes from 192.168.82.1#53 in 0 ms
```

Is there anyway that I can simply read write the section between `;; ANSWER SECTION:` and `Received 1108 bytes from 192.168.82.1#53 in 0 ms` to a file using simple terminal command ? I am reading about `awk` but I don't understand how I can use it to print only certain part of the output of the command.

**Expected output**

```
abc.unix
xyz.unix
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are right the `awk` command is very handy for this situation.

Give a try to this:

```
awk '/^;; ANSWER SECTION:/ , /^Received [0-9]* bytes from [0-9.#]* in [0-9.] ms/ {if ($0 !~ /^;; ANSWER SECTION:/ && $0 !~ /^Received [0-9]* bytes from [0-9.#]* in [0-9.] ms/) print}'
```

The test:

```
$ host -a -l mydomain.com | awk '/^;; ANSWER SECTION:/ , /^Received [0-9]* bytes from [0-9.#]* in [0-9.] ms/ {if ($0 !~ /^;; ANSWER SECTION:/ && $0 !~ /^Received [0-9]* bytes from [0-9.#]* in [0-9.] ms/) print}'
abc.unix
xyz.unix
```

Comment: this command expect `output` to be a file path yeah ? but I have to use a command not a file. I tried `| host -a -l mydomain.com` where you write `output` in your command, but it didn't work

Comment: @RileyWillow could you try: `host -a -l mydomain.com | awk '/^;; ANSWER SECTION:/ , /^Received [0-9]* bytes from [0-9.#]* in [0-9.] ms/ {if ($0 !~ /^;; ANSWER SECTION:/ && $0 !~ /^Received [0-9]* bytes from [0-9.#]* in [0-9.] ms/) print}'`

Comment: fantastic ! it works, i was doing the piping wrong :) Thanks heaps

Answer (score 3):

In awk you could try this:

```
awk '$0~/;; ANSWER SECTION:/{a=1; next}
     (a && $0 !~/^Received/)' input
```

The output for the given example

```
abc.unix
xyz.unix
```

The first line sets `a=1` when the current line contains ";; ANSWER SECTION:". If `a=1` **and** the current line does not start with "Received", then we print the entire line. (If you want to suppress empty lines, you could add `&& $0 != ""` to `(a && $0 !~/^Received/)`)

In combination with your command `host -a -l mydomain.com`:

```
host -a -l mydomain.com | awk '$0~/;; ANSWER SECTION:/{a=1; next}
         (a && $0 !~/^Received/)'
```

Comment: in your answer, i have to write a file name for `input`, yeah ? but I need to provide a command instead of a file, i.e. `host -a -l mydomain.com`.

Comment: Do i have to first save the output of the command in a file and then run your command for that file ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple requirement where `sed` could be used

```
hostname -a -l mydomain.com | sed -n '/;; ANSWER/{n;N;p;q}'
```

would do it.

Output

```
abc.unix
xyz.unix
```

The `q` command is handy as it will stop processing once the required portion is printed.